# IntelliJ Install Missing Python Packages

Tags: python

I#m getting confusing messages from IntelliJ when installing missing python packages as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

It says that kfp is installed, but then it throws up the message in the source file saying it cannot find kfp. Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: PyCharm ? which version ?

Comment: Not PyCharm, but just IntelliJ

Comment: @joesan Try to Invalidate caches

Comment: That did not help either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes weird things happen with Intellij. I occasionally get the similar errors with Maven Plugin, when it tells you it cannot find packages, while they are obviously istalled. Here is what might help:

Go to:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches...
```

Press:

```
Invalidate and Restart
```